# Debian 11: Libreoffice crashes at once

Tags: debian, libreoffice

I have installed Debian 11 from scratch (it is not a Debian 10 upgrade).

When I open Calc and push any one key, Libreoffice crashes and this also happens in safe mode.

I tried to gather some logs, but I am afraid that they do not contain enough information.

**Update**

This is the result of the command:
`strace libreoffice 2>&1`:

https://pastebin.com/eipFqXvu

Libre Office:

```
Version: 7.0.4.2
Build ID: 00(Build:2)
CPU threads: 4; OS: Linux 5.10; UI render: default; VCL: gtk3
Locale: en-US (en_US.utf8); UI: en-US
Debian package version: 1:7.0.4-4+deb11u1
Calc: threaded
```

uname -a

```
Linux flyer 5.10.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.70-1 (2021-09-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Some hardware info

```
OptiPlex 790
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz
4GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
4GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
```

The logs I found:

```
    # journalctl -e
    Oct 18 22:44:12 flyer soffice.bin[12165]: Negative content width -12 (allocation 1, extents 6x7) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkButton)
    Oct 18 22:44:12 flyer soffice.bin[12165]: Negative content width -12 (allocation 1, extents 6x7) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkButton)
    Oct 18 22:44:12 flyer soffice.bin[12165]: Negative content width -12 (allocation 1, extents 6x7) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkButton)
    Oct 18 22:44:12 flyer soffice.bin[12165]: Negative content width -12 (allocation 1, extents 6x7) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkButton)
    Oct 18 22:44:12 flyer soffice.bin[12165]: Negative content width -12 (allocation 1, extents 6x7) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkButton)
    Oct 18 22:44:30 flyer audit[12165]: AVC apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/usr/local/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0" pid=12165 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r>
    Oct 18 22:44:30 flyer audit[12165]: AVC apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_mmap" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/usr/local/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0" pid=12165 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="rm" denied_m>
    Oct 18 22:44:30 flyer kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1634586270.897:77): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/usr/local/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0" pid=12165 comm="soffice.bin" >
    Oct 18 22:44:30 flyer kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1634586270.897:78): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_mmap" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/usr/local/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0" pid=12165 comm="soffice.>
    Oct 18 22:44:30 flyer audit[12165]: AVC apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/home/flyer/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distutils-precedence.pth" pid=12165 comm="soffice.b>
    Oct 18 22:44:30 flyer kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1634586270.913:79): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/home/flyer/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distutils-preceden>
    Oct 18 22:45:01 flyer CRON[12280]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
    Oct 18 22:45:01 flyer CRON[12281]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
    Oct 18 22:45:01 flyer CRON[12280]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
    Oct 18 22:48:27 flyer gnome-shell[2713]: libinput error: event4  - Logitech USB Keyboard: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 25ms, your system is too slow
    Oct 18 22:50:43 flyer systemd[1]: Starting system activity accounting tool...
    Oct 18 22:50:43 flyer systemd[1]: sysstat-collect.service: Succeeded.
    Oct 18 22:50:43 flyer systemd[1]: Finished system activity accounting tool.
    Oct 18 22:50:54 flyer gnome-shell[2713]: libinput error: event3  - Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 13ms, your system is too slow
    Oct 18 22:50:59 flyer systemd[2539]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
    Oct 18 22:51:00 flyer rtkit-daemon[963]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
    Oct 18 22:51:00 flyer rtkit-daemon[963]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
    Oct 18 22:51:00 flyer rtkit-daemon[963]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
    Oct 18 22:51:00 flyer rtkit-daemon[963]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
    Oct 18 22:51:00 flyer rtkit-daemon[963]: Successfully made thread 12513 of process 12442 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
    Oct 18 22:51:00 flyer rtkit-daemon[963]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
    Oct 18 22:51:00 flyer rtkit-daemon[963]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
    Oct 18 22:51:00 flyer rtkit-daemon[963]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
    Oct 18 22:51:01 flyer rtkit-daemon[963]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
    Oct 18 22:51:01 flyer rtkit-daemon[963]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
    Oct 18 22:51:02 flyer rtkit-daemon[963]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
    Oct 18 22:51:02 flyer rtkit-daemon[963]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
    Oct 18 22:51:03 flyer rtkit-daemon[963]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
    Oct 18 22:51:03 flyer rtkit-daemon[963]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
    Oct 18 22:51:03 flyer systemd[2539]: app-gnome-firefox\x2desr-4679.scope: Succeeded.
    Oct 18 22:51:03 flyer systemd[2539]: app-gnome-firefox\x2desr-4679.scope: Consumed 50min 25.087s CPU time.
    Oct 18 22:51:59 flyer systemd[2539]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
    Oct 18 22:51:59 flyer libreoffice-calc.desktop[12680]: Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
    Oct 18 22:52:00 flyer gnome-shell[2713]: libinput error: event3  - Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 22ms, your system is too slow
    Oct 18 22:52:01 flyer systemd[2539]: app-gnome-libreoffice\x2dcalc-12680.scope: Succeeded.
    Oct 18 22:52:01 flyer systemd[2539]: app-gnome-libreoffice\x2dcalc-12680.scope: Consumed 1.412s CPU time.
    Oct 18 22:52:18 flyer audit[12226]: AVC apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/usr/local/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0" pid=12226 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r>
    Oct 18 22:52:18 flyer audit[12226]: AVC apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_mmap" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/usr/local/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0" pid=12226 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="rm" denied_m>
    Oct 18 22:52:18 flyer kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1634586738.092:80): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/usr/local/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0" pid=12226 comm="soffice.bin" >
    Oct 18 22:52:18 flyer kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1634586738.092:81): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_mmap" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/usr/local/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0" pid=12226 comm="soffice.>
    Oct 18 22:52:18 flyer audit[12226]: AVC apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/home/flyer/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distutils-precedence.pth" pid=12226 comm="soffice.b>
    Oct 18 22:52:18 flyer kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1634586738.112:82): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/home/flyer/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distutils-preceden>
```

Comment: Welcome, does it happens with the other libreoffice programs, like Writer?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Yes, with writer I tested and it happens. I have not tested with the other programs. When I get back to that box I will also test with a live CD and report back.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Writer and Draw will start and crash, impress will not start at all.... I have updated my question with the result of the command `strace libreoffice` for the calc crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apt purge libreoffice*  # (The asterisk is crucial)
apt autoremove
apt install libreoffice
```

A completely new environment of `libreoffice` emerged and works.